# Регулярное выражение с < br />

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте!

```
$arr_content =  preg_split("/[.?!] /", $content);
```

Это разделит текст на предложения по точке пробелу, `?` пробелу и `!` пробелу.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как к списку символов добавить ещё `<br />`?
Получить нужно список предложений, которые есть в $content.

Comment: ну так и добавьте его через "или" (`|`): `/[.?!] |<br \/>/`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$arr_content =  preg_split("/[.?!] |(<br \/>)/", $content);
```

Comment: Просто скопировали комментарий эксперта? А объяснить?

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, информацию о том, почему это работает.

Comment: Спасибо, такой вариант работает, правда в списке предложений есть пустые, но на вопрос ответили!